# Recognize any sound in android speech recognition

Tags: java, android, speech-recognition, speech-to-text

I would like to use [android's speechRecognizer](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/speech/SpeechRecognizer) to recognize sounds, which are not just words but any syllables (for example a baby saying "ba"/"ma").

This seems to be possible in python using the `speech_recognition` module, but I can't find a way to do so in java.

The code skeleton I have so far is as follows:

```
final Intent speechRecognizerIntent = new Intent(RecognizerIntent.ACTION_RECOGNIZE_SPEECH);

speechRecognizerIntent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE_MODEL,RecognizerIntent.LANGUAGE_MODEL_FREE_FORM);
speechRecognizerIntent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE, Locale.getDefault());

speechRecognizer.startListening(speechRecognizerIntent);
```

Comment: `speech_recognition` is a generic library capable of working with several backends, and providing more advanced setting. The `ACTION_RECOGNIZE_SPEECH` is a simplified API specifically to decipher language using Googles language engine, and to my knowledge there is no way to use it to do what you want. You could try looking at how the Python library works with Google's web API, which has more options, record the sounds your self and send them to the web API.

Comment: @LevM. In that case, isn't there a simpler library in java that does that?

Comment: You might want to have a look at PocketSphinx on android (https://cmusphinx.github.io/wiki/tutorialandroid/). It is not really simple but quite flexible.

Comment: There might be, but if I knew of one and how to use it, I would post a proper answer for you...